# VBA Property calling Get instead of Let

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I'm trying to implement an interface so that I can have multiple models and can pass different models in to different methods. In this instance I am trying to set a workbook variable but can not seem to understand why this is calling get method instead of the let.

The method that is setting the value:

```
Public Sub OpenAllWorkbooks(ByRef fromCopyItems As Collection)
    Dim currentCopyItem As ICopyItem
    Dim wb As Variant

    For Each currentCopyItem In fromCopyItems
        ' Set currentCopyItem.ItemWorkBook = OpenWorkbook(currentCopyItem.WorkbookPath) I commented this out to make sure that was set currentCopyItem = whatever was the error
        Set wb = OpenWorkbook(currentCopyItem.WorkbookPath)
        Set currentCopyItem.ItemWorkBook = wb ' It breaks here
        currentCopyItem.IsOpen = True
    Next currentCopyItem

End Sub
```

This is in the Expense Model that implements ICopyItem:

```
'Calling this instead of let
Public Property Get ICopyItem_ItemWorkBook() As Workbook
    Set ICopyItem_ItemWorkBook = Item.ItemWorkBook 
End Property
```

This is what it should be calling:

```
Public Property Let ICopyItem_ItemWorkBook(value As Workbook)
    Set Item.ItemWorkBook = value
End Property
```

can someone please explain why this is happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem here is that you defined a `Property Let` accessor instead of a `Property Set` accessor. `Property Let` is generally meant for the assigment of value types and `Property Set` for the assignment of object types.

The call to the `Property Get` happens because of the following paragraph in section 5.4.3.9 of the [VBE Language specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx), which describes the fallback mechanism in case there is no `Property Set`.

> If *l-expression* is classified as a property or function and refers to an 
>   enclosing 
>   Property Get
>   or function, assign the coerced expression value to the enclosing procedure’s return value.